# How to mention function closing curly brace in echo of string html code?

Tags: php, string, foreach, echo, curly-braces

I'm trying to close this foreach function curly brace inside echo, while the function itself is outside of the echoed html code.

```
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product) {
echo

"<form class='info-confrim' action='includes/info.inc.php' method='post'>

    <input type='hidden' name='product-name' value=".$product['name'].">
    <input type='hidden' name='amount' value=".$product["quantity"].">
    <input type='hidden' name='total-price' value=".$product['price'].">

            ".}."

    <button class='submit-button' type='submit' name='info- 
submit'>SUBMIT</button>

 </form>";
```

I want the button to be outside for-each function so that it won't repeat itself but this method is not working at this time. I know I don't have enough knowledge and that's why I'm here.

Comment: Why not use two echoes? One inside the `foreach` loop, and one outside.

Comment: Isn't this going to affect form tag? like making it two separate piece. are they going to stay attached onto each other and work fine?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work. This is another way of making for-each loop or any other statement ( if, while...) without curly brace

```
<form class='info-confrim' action='includes/info.inc.php' method='post'>

<?php foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product): ?>

    <input type='hidden' name='product-name' value=".$product['name'].">
    <input type='hidden' name='amount' value=".$product["quantity"].>">
    <input type='hidden' name='total-price' value=".$product['price'].">

<?php endforeach; ?>

<button class='submit-button' type='submit' name='info-submit'>SUBMIT</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: What is `".$product['name']."`?

Comment: @Dharman I did not edit any of that part just particular question about for-each loop